# Concrete5 Multiple file upload error:404 in firefox

Tags: php, firefox, file-upload, concrete5

Multiple file upload error:
`404 in Firefox browser` .

Check this [link](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/14061/20121227-qnug-29kb.jpg)

Comment: I have tried to upload multiple files in concrete5 using firefox . single file upload works correctly

Comment: Are you familiar with the web developer console? Can you report what the URL of the page you're on is, and the URL of the upload attempts, and if, in fact, they're 404'ing at the HTML level.

Answer (score 1):

I would open up the console like James suggested. This may have something to do with the way your server is configured. Have you verified that it works in other browsers such as Chrome?

There is are a lot of helpful post on the concrete5 forums about issues like this. Here is one that might help:

http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/installation/solved-uploads-not-working/

Here are a few other posts that might also be helpful:

http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/installation/multiple-file-uploading-not-working/
http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/usage/file-manager-multiple-upload-not-working/
http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/usage/error_trying_to_upload_multiple_files_take_2/

I will need more information in order to provide you with a more helpful answer. I would have left a comment but don't have enough reputation.